# svg and angularjs - a simple ngClick example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg

I have a simple problem (I hope). I would like to bind so to say svg element and angularjs. Here how the problem looks like:

`<svg> <g ...> <text ... ng-click="count=count+1" ng-init="count=0">Click me!</text></g></svg>`

outside `<svg>` I have the following code:

`count: {{count}}`

I would like to clik on "Click me!" and see how many clicks did I make. That does not work. I see no result, my question is why? This is nothing more then the example from the AngularJs webpage:
[ngClick example from AngularJs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngClick).

When I use that example without/outside `<svg>` (let say with button - like it is in official AngularJs webpage):

`<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0">
  Click me!
</button>`

The AngularJs does his work. Are there any restrictions regarding `<svg>` and AngularJs? or perhaps I have to use some trick to use it?

Great thanks in advance for any tip or help!

nykon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular directives will work just fine inside of SVG. See the below code, using your ng-click function:

```
count: {{count}}
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle ng-click="count=count+1" ng-init="count=0" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" />
</svg>
```

SVG with angular ng-click example in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/KvHKa68oZ6YxQIJzyIXG?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

Note that, to be accessed by javascript, loaded SVG files follow the same set of rules as other contents. that means **Same origin Policy** may cause some troubles if you load your SVG from a different domain or a FILE source (that means your code MAY start working if you put it on a server like localhost)

To access / reference SVG nodes you can use certain javascript libraries like [Raphaël.js](http://raphaeljs.com/), although you can use straight java-script as well

hope it helps