# How to pass a variable from jQuery to AngularJs function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, arrays

I have this function on  my Controller

I use this function to save the id of a svg path on one array when I click on a part of the image.svg

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var arrayCuerpo=[];
        $('.SaveBody').on("click", function() {

            var idCuerpo=jQuery(this).attr("id");
            var parteCuerpo=CambiarCuerpo(idCuerpo);

            if( jQuery.inArray(parteCuerpo,arrayCuerpo) == -1){//No existe
                $('path#'+idCuerpo).css({ fill: "#4C9141",stroke: "#4C9141" });
                arrayCuerpo.push(parteCuerpo);
                //console.log("if");
                console.log(arrayCuerpo);
            }else{//existe
                $('path#'+idCuerpo).css({ fill: "#9e9e9e",stroke: "#9e9e9e" });
                arrayCuerpo.removeItem(parteCuerpo);

               // console.log("else");
                console.log(arrayCuerpo);
                $scope.arrayCuerpo =arrayCuerpo;
            }
        });

    });
```

And I wanna acces to the array : arrayCuerpo on this function on the same Controller:

```
    $scope.SendForm1 = function(){

        console.log($scope.arrayCuerpo);
         //This return undefined
    }

SendForm1 is called when I put my Send Button Form

Could u help me to pass that array in that Function pls?
```

**EDIT the Solution:**

```
I wasnt calling the ng-controlelr on the svg-image
For pass the variable i just created a service .factory

app.factory('yourService', function () {
    var array = [];

    return {
        setData: function setData(data) {
            array = data;
        },

        getData: function getData() {
            return array;
        }
    };
});
```

with this i can call the service on the function with :

```
yourService.setData($scope.arrayCuerpo);
```

and then i get the data with:

```
$scope.Array = yourService.getData();
```

Comment: i would like to suggest to using ng-click on the element rather than using on 'click' on jquery to trigger 'clicked' event.
<div class='SaveBody' ng-click="sendForm1"></div>
you are able to do doom manipulation with jquery on SendForm1 function scope code.

Comment: i forget to say that i´m using that class (SaveBody) on a svg path .. ( <path class="SaveBody..>) so i cant use ng-click on path :S

Comment: I see. so one option that you could use is using global JavaScript variable (this is not recommended).
but if you like to integrate svg tag with angularjs ng-click, might be this link could help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/29868537/5129606

Comment: ng-click doesnt work :( , when i click on the part of the img it does nothing  , not alert or console.log inside that function

Comment: was my fault, on the svg-image  wasn´t  calling the ng-controller!

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this:

```
$scope.SendForm1 = function(arrayCuerpo){
$scope.arrayCuerpo=arrayCuerpo;
    console.log(arrayCuerpo);
     //This return undefined
}
```

Comment: how to call you this function?

Comment: SendForm1 is called when I put my Send Button Form

Comment: calling function like this `SendForm1(Your Array);`